# Magento Patch SUPEE-6788 breaks custom file option file link on cart page?

Tags: magento

When executing file upload on a site with SUPEE-6788 applied, and then adding the product to cart, rather than present a URL to the uploaded file you get a chunk of text similar to this on the shopping cart page and also in the sales email generate.  The file itself can be found in the quote folder so looks like the rerendered part of the page that should show the file link is bust.

```
a:10:{s:4:"type";s:10:"image/jpeg";s:5:"title";s:8:"2849.jpg";s:10:"quote_path";s:68:"/media/custom_options/quote/2/8/16156fb1e8320b06153ee7061a7b5cdf.jpg";s:10:"order_path";s:68:"/media/custom_options/order/2/8/16156fb1e8320b06153ee7061a7b5cdf.jpg";s:8:"fullpath";s:119:"
```

Has anyone else seen this issue.

** update **
This is still a problem after upgrading to 1.9.2.4.

Interestingly if you update and save the cart the uploaded file link is then rendered correctly.  In the sales_flat_quote_item_option table where the product options in the cart are saved, the field holding the file link metadata is updated and it has changed.  Some characters present in the value on the original cart submission are removed [see below]

```
;s:3:"url";a:2:{s:5:"route";s:35:"sales/download/downloadCustomOption";s:6:"params";a:2:{s:2:"id";N;s:3:"key";s:20:"d6e5b846b9f1f6b4298b";}}}
```

Therefore rather than a rendering issue it looks like a generation issue. Maybe the theme is involved. Will look at difference between writing and regeneration.

** Update **
OK solution found.  The Application (Magento Theme + Modules) was, in a Mage_Checkout_CartController type, creating a product in the cart via code like this

```
$cart   = $this->_getCart();
$params = $this->getRequest()->getParams();
$_product = $this->_initProduct();
$cart->addProduct($_product, $params);
```

This was creating a product that contained the File Upload option which was then stored in an invalid format.

A rework of the code removed the need to use the above code and the problem has gone.  So there does seem to be a bug somewhere related to product creation and File Upload options but I've gone far enough on this journey for now.

Answer (score 0):

Same here this problem is encountered within many instances, like product page, checkout page, order page (Magento CMS). First we thought it was about module update issue, but that didn't help, so right now we think it's a 1.9.2.2 bug.

Comment: This is a non-answer. Please restrict a remark like this to the comments.